# undefined method `two_dimensional?' using Barby CairoOutputter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cairo

I just want to generate a QR code using rqrcode gem. When I create my new rqrcode instance:

```
qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new('test')
```

I get the following input :

```
xxxxxxx  x  x x  xxxxxx x xxxxxxx
x     x xx xxxxx     xx   x     x
x xxx x   x   x xxxx  xx  x xxx x
x xxx x   x x x x  x x xx x xxx x
x xxx x  x   xxx xxx    x x xxx x
x     x xxx  x    xx      x     x
xxxxxxx x x x x x x x x x xxxxxxx
        x x     xx   x x         
    xxxx  xxxxx  xxxx   x xx   x 
 x  xx xxxx   xxxx xxxx    x  xxx
xx x xx   x x  xxxx            xx
  x  x x  xxx xxxxxxx x xx xxx  x
x  xxxxxxx x x x xxxx xx xx  xx  
x x x         xx xxx x  x xxxx   
xx   xxx  xxx xxx   x  xxxxx xxx 
xx   x   xx     xxx   xx  x   x  
   x  xxxx xx    xxxx x x  x  x x
 x xxx  x x x   xx  x    xx  xx x
xxx  xx xx     x   x xx     xx   
     x x x        x xx  xx xx  x 
x  xxxx xx xx  x  x x  xxxx    xx
x x x      xxx x     xx   xxx xxx
    x xx  x xxx  x       x x   xx
    xx   x xxx xxxx x x x    x  x
xx x xxxx xx   x    x xxxxxxxxx  
        x  xx xx x x   xx   xx  x
xxxxxxx xx x        xxxxx x xxx  
x     x xx xx   x xxxx xx   x xx 
x xxx x xx  x     xxx   xxxxx xxx
x xxx x    xx  x     xxxxxxxx xxx
x xxx x   x xx        xx    x    
x     x   xxxxxxxxx x xx xx xx   
xxxxxxx  x xx  x xx    x x x xx x
```

For printing my qr_code I use the CairoOutputter of Barby but when I try to convert my output to svg, png,... I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `two_dimensional?' for #<RQRCode::QRCode:0x0000000794bd88>)
```

Do you have any ideas of what I can do to correct this error?

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rqrcode','~> 0.4.2'
gem 'barby'
gem 'cairo'
```

In my model:

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/outputter/cairo_outputter'
require 'rqrcode'
qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new('test')
puts  qr
outputter = Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr).to_svg
```

Comment: outputter = Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr).to_svg

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal, verifiable example? This may be a bug in the library, which may be better raised as an issue in the github project directly...

Comment: qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new('test')
puts  qr
outputter = Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr).to_svg

Comment: does this work? `Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr.to_s).to_svg`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I cast qr instance to string, I get the follow error message: undefined method `two_dimensional?' for #<String:0x0000000fc66da8>

Comment: @SimonSabbatini Please could you provide a **complete** example? Which gem(s) do I need to install? What files do I need to `require`? Please **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44408548/edit)** to provide enough information that someone who is not already familiar with the tool can reproduce the problem easily.

Comment: It looks like I need to `gem install barby`, `gem install cairo`, `require  'barby/outputter/cairo_outputter'`, ...... How many more steps are there? I don't know. Please provide all the information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TomLord, My post is edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the project `README`](https://github.com/toretore/barby#supported-symbologies), you need to use one of the supported `barcode` classes. Namely, you need to use `Barby::QrCode`, not `RQRCode::QRCode`.

With the following libraries installed:

```
gem install 'barby'   # core library
gem install 'cairo'   # dependency for output
gem install 'rqrcode' # dependency for barcode
```

The following implementation works fine:

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/outputter/cairo_outputter'
require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'

qr = Barby::QrCode.new('test')
outputter = Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr).to_svg
```

Unlike `RQRCode::QRCode`, `Barby::QrCode` implements methods such as `two_dimensional?` and `encoding` - which are required by the `Barby::CairoOutputter` implementation.

Comment: I've also try it but the output of qr instance is 'test'. So my svg is a white image...